# JavaSimon 4.1.1 add time

Tags: java, stopwatch

Are there any ways to add time to existing stopwatch, as it was available in <=3.0 ?

```
public Stopwatch addTime(long time) {}
```

I cannot find any similar methods in new Simon..

Answer (score 1):

Answer has found:

```
addSplit(Split.create(time));
```